# Blender 2.81a wont work with my Wacom tablet

Tags: sculpting, eevee-render-engine, 2d

Just downloaded blender 2.81a wont work with my Intous Paper. it is working with both 2.8 and photoshop so im pretty sure its a problem with 2.81a. the tablet will work with 2D in 2.81a but not sculpting for some reason. thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you test if that happens without using the tablet as well?

Comment: do you use the pressure sensitive settings in that mode?

Comment: It works perfectly well when i use just a mouse but sculoting with a mouse is near impossible to me.

Comment: I always use pressure sensitivity i believe.